# Jquery, .length + 1 seems to be adding multiples of 7

Tags: jquery, html

I have a jquery script to add some input fields at the click of a button, I need these to be numbering up, so there are 4 fields called first:

JSFIDDLE LINK  http://jsfiddle.net/1orkxk2y/

```
ptno1
desc1
qty1
amnt1
```

when add field is clicked I expected this to be but I ended up with the numbers in brackets:

```
ptno2(7)
desc2(7)
qty2(7)
amnt2(7)
```

Code below:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $("#add").click(function() {
        var intId = $("#test div").length + 1;
        var fieldWrapper = $("<div id=\"test\" class=\"row\"/>");
        var fptno = $("<div class=\"col-md-2\"><input type=\"text\" name=\"ptno" + intId + "\" class=\"form-control\" /></>");
        var fdesc = $("<div class=\"col-md-2\"><input type=\"text\" name=\"desc" + intId + "\" class=\"form-control\" /></>");
        var fqty = $("<div class=\"col-md-2\"><input type=\"text\" name=\"qty" + intId + "\" class=\"form-control\" /></>");
        var famnt = $("<div class=\"col-md-2\"><input type=\"text\" name=\"amnt" + intId + "\" class=\"form-control\" /></>");
        var removeButton = $("<div class=\"col-md-2\"><input type=\"button\" class=\"remove\" value=\"-\" /></>");
        removeButton.click(function() {
            $(this).parent().remove();
        });
        fieldWrapper.append(fptno);
        fieldWrapper.append(fdesc);
        fieldWrapper.append(fqty);
        fieldWrapper.append(famnt);
        fieldWrapper.append(removeButton);
        $("#buildyourform").append(fieldWrapper);
    });
});

<fieldset id="buildyourform">
</fieldset>
<input type="button" value="Add a charge" class="add" id="add" />
```

Comment: `.length` returns the number of `<div>` elements belonging to `#test`, + 1. Is this what you're intending?

Comment: No I would prefer it to be the number of rows, so first set should have 1 and the second set 2 and so on

Comment: @TimLewis are you sure about this ? ;) I think $('#test').length returns number of elements with that id

Comment: @MarkoMackic Yeah, `$('#test').length` would, but would `$("#test div").length`? It's a different selector. Also, id's should be unique, so `$("#anything").length` should only **ever** return 1.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The expression `$("#test div")` will get **every div** inside **every #test**. Since you add 5 div inside `#test` each time, the `length` attribute will increment by 5. Perhaps you could simply use a global variable instead of reading the DOM each time?

```
var intId = 1;

$(document).ready(function() {
    $("#add").click(function() {
        var fieldWrapper = $("<div id=\"test\" class=\"row\"/>");
        var fptno = $("<div class=\"col-md-2\"><input type=\"text\" name=\"ptno" + intId + "\" class=\"form-control\" /></>");
        ...
        intId++;
    });
});
```

Edit: Thanks [Tim Lewis](https://stackoverflow.com/users/3965631/tim-lewis) for pointing out that multiple `id` attributes produces invalid HTML.

Comment: And I'll say it again, make sure not to repeat `id` attributes, they need to be unique, so having multiple `<div id="test">` elements is invalid.

Comment: Just posted an answer that doesn't use duplicate ids, for reference

Answer (score 0):

First of, when you're appending to something make sure that you close the element tag, and secondly you can't query `$('#test div'`) because it will query the `divs` inside the id named `test`, no matter the level. So your code should be :

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    function reIndex(){
      $('.test').each(function(index,element){    
         $(element).children().each(function(){    
           var inp_elem = $(this).children("input");
           if(inp_elem.attr("name").split("_").length == 2)
             {
              inp_elem.attr("name",inp_elem.attr("name").split("_")[0] + "_" + (index+1));
             }
      });
    });
    }
    $("#add").click(function() {
        var intId = $(".test").length + 1;
        var fieldWrapper = $("<div class=\"test row\"/></div>");
        var fptno = $("<div class=\"col-md-2\"><input type=\"text\" name=\"ptno_" + intId + "\" class=\"form-control\" /></div>");
        var fdesc = $("<div class=\"col-md-2\"><input type=\"text\" name=\"desc_" + intId + "\" class=\"form-control\" /></div>");
        var fqty = $("<div class=\"col-md-2\"><input type=\"text\" name=\"qty_" + intId + "\" class=\"form-control\" /></div>");
        var famnt = $("<div class=\"col-md-2\"><input type=\"text\" name=\"amnt_" + intId + "\" class=\"form-control\" /></div>");
        var removeButton = $("<div class=\"col-md-2\"><input type=\"button\" class=\"remove\" value=\"-\" /></div>");
        removeButton.click(function() {
            $(this).parent().remove();
            reIndex();
        });
        fieldWrapper.append(fptno);
        fieldWrapper.append(fdesc);
        fieldWrapper.append(fqty);
        fieldWrapper.append(famnt);
        fieldWrapper.append(removeButton);
        $("#buildyourform").append(fieldWrapper);
    });
});
```

I missed a thing [Does ID have to be unique in the whole page?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9454645/does-id-have-to-be-unique-in-the-whole-page) ID of element has to be unique because it gives an element a name, so you could use it with a class `test`.
EDIT: I added reindexing when element is removed, so the indexing would be consistent and no overlaps will occur :) and here is a new fiddle http://jsfiddle.net/1orkxk2y/3/

Comment: That looks better; Only issue I can see is if you have 3 elements `<div class="test">` and you remove number 2, then create another one, you all of a sudden have multiple `<input name="ptno3">` elements :P

Comment: Well yeah :P correct answer doesn't address this issue too but I could do reindexing :P

Comment: Actually Simon's does, since it uses an internal counter, so you'll never end up with the same `intID` twice. Just needs a bit more refactoring lol There's other solutions, like assigning the input names/index after appending/removing, but that's the fun of JS; so many solutions to the same problem

Comment: yeah, I thought you were talking about consistence of numbering

Answer (score 0):

`$("#test div").length` is returning the number of `div` elements that have a parent with an `id` of test.  Currently, you are generating a new container for these inputs, all with an `id` of test, so they all meet the criteria for the selector.

I'd like to point out, first, that creating multiple elements with the same `id` is **invalid HTML**.  Something you can do to address the iterator and duplicate `id` problems in one swoop is to use the `row` class that you're already placing on your input containers:

```
$("#add").click(function() {
        var intId = $(".row").length + 1;
        var fieldWrapper = $("<div class=\"row\"/>");
        var fptno = $("<div class=\"col-md-2\"><input type=\"text\" name=\"ptno" + intId + "\" class=\"form-control\" /></>");
        var fdesc = $("<div class=\"col-md-2\"><input type=\"text\" name=\"desc" + intId + "\" class=\"form-control\" /></>");
        ...
```

No global iterator, just utilizing classes you're already using.